# collapse list of int to list of ranges in kotlin

Tags: collections, functional-programming, kotlin

I have a list of ints that needs to be compressed to list of int ranges without loosing any information (there must be a way to reverse this operation).

Currently I have:

```
val ints = listOf(8, 9, 45, 48, 49, 60, 61, 61, 62, 63, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6)
val out = ints
        .map { it..it }
        .fold(mutableListOf(ints[0]..(ints[0] - 1)),
                { acc, next ->
                    val prev = acc.last()
                    if (prev.last + 1 == next.first) {
                        acc[acc.lastIndex] = prev.first..next.last
                    } else {
                        acc.add(next)
                    }
                    acc
                }).toList()
```

That correctly produces:

```
[8..9, 45..45, 48..49, 60..61, 61..63, 3..5, 4..6]
```

There are two aspects I dislike in my solution though,

1. it does not work for empty list because of fold's initial value
2. it's quite verbose for kotlin. I have a feeling that this can be resolved in bit nicer way.

So, the question is how to fix 1 and/or 2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution doesn't look much different, but I was able to fix your empty list issue:

```
val out = ints.fold(mutableListOf<IntRange>()) { acc, next ->
    acc.apply {
        if(isNotEmpty() && last().endInclusive.inc() == next) {
            this[lastIndex] = this[lastIndex].start .. next
        } else {
            add(next..next)
        }
    }
}
```

It's also a bit less mapping, and using apply takes away some of the verbosity and having to refer to `acc` at the end.

Comment: I like it's indeed simplified and as single expression. BTW, Any Idea how/if using lambda in the loop affects performance compared to raw imperative loop?

Comment: Since `apply` is an [`inline` function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html), its usage in the loop does not affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

Since you actually mutate the `acc` and return the same list of ranges at all iterations of `fold`, you may not really need the `fold`, that is, `forEach` is enough.

Then, mapping each number to `it..it` seems to be redundant here.

Taking the two notes above into account leads to the following, a bit simplified, version of your solution:

```
val result = mutableListOf<IntRange>()
ints.forEach {
    val lastRange = result.lastOrNull()
    if (lastRange?.endInclusive == it - 1)
        result[result.lastIndex] = lastRange.first..it
    else
        result += it..it
}
```

---

UPD: with the addition of [`buildList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html) to the Kotlin standard library, you can rewrite the above as:

```kotlin
val result = buildList {
    ints.forEach {
        val last = lastOrNull()
        if (last?.endInclusive == it -1) {
            set(lastIndex, last.start..it)
        } else {
            add(it..it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like you solution. Thanks @hotkey for the valuable tips. I was having hard time picking answer to accept. Picked Todd's for single expression. I know yours can be transformed as well via `apply`.

Comment: No problem. Though I personally think that adding another nesting level and making the receiver implicit with `apply` may reduce readability, this is rather opinion-based judgement.